# Why does this dictionary, returned by Sympy, appear to have and also not have the key 'w'?

Tags: python, dictionary, sympy

I have a dictionary returned by [Sympy](https://www.sympy.org/). It appears to have an entry with a key, `w`.

```py
>>> stationary_points
{w: 542.962336871418, b: 0.887349275879595}
>>> type(stationary_points)
<class 'dict'>
```

And I don't know why but it also appears *not* to have an entry with the key  `w`:

```py
>>> stationary_points.get('w')
None
>>> stationary_points['w']
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
KeyError: 'w'
```

Does this dictionary have key `w` or not? Why the apparently contradictory behaviour?

Comment: Looks like the keys are not `str` types. Could you print the value of `type(list(stationary_points.keys())[0])`?

Comment: @OluwafemiSule this is its type `<class 'sympy.core.symbol.Symbol'>` Actually this dict is returned by [Sympy](https://www.sympy.org/).

Comment: Try it with `stationary_points[symbols('w')]`.

Comment: A) Whatever you’re printing for `out` probably isn’t actually a dictionary but has it __repr__()` defined to present it as one. Or b) in the output you show the key isn’t `’w’`, it’s `w` - se the difference?

Comment: What @aneroid wrote or `stationary_points[Symbol('w')]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Short answer

The keys are not of type `string` they are of type `<class 'sympy.core.symbol.Symbol'>`. And to get key values you can do this:

```py
>>> from sympy import Symbol
>>> stationary_points[Symbol('w')]
542.962336871418
>>> stationary_points[Symbol('b')]
0.887349275879595
```

## Long answer

A python dictionary can have keys of type other than `str` for example:

```py
class myClass:
  pass

a = 1.1
obj = myClass()

mydict = {
  'str': 'str',
  1: 1,
  a: 1.1,
  obj: 'my obj'
}
```

Now if we print that dictionary we get this result:

```py
>>> mydict
{
  'str': 'str',
  1: 1,
  1.1: 1.1,
  <__main__.myClass object at 0x00000200B0297908>: 'my obj'
}
```

Here we can clearly see that only first key has quotes around it and not the others. And this tells that only first one is of type string not the others. And if you want to get non string key values then you'll have to provide that object.

```py
>>> mydict['str']
'str'
>>> mydict[1]
1
>>> mydict[1.1]
1.1
>>> mydict[a]      # We can also provide dynamic key with variables
1.1
>>> mydict[obj]
'my obj'
```

Now in your case the keys are not of type string but some other type because they don't have quotes around them:

```py
>>> stationary_points
{w: 542.962336871418, b: 0.887349275879595}
```

You can see the type of key using this method

```py
>>> type(list(stationary_points.keys())[0])
<class 'sympy.core.symbol.Symbol'>
```

So the keys are actually of type sympy `Symbol` class. So now you can access the value using this method:

```py
>>> from sympy import Symbol
>>> stationary_points[Symbol('w')]
542.962336871418
>>> stationary_points[Symbol('b')]
0.887349275879595
```

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that the `w` you see in the dictionary isn't a string. You can try:

```
for k in stationary_points:
    print(k, stationary_points[k], type(k))
```

to see what type of objects you're dealing with.

Comment: Yes, it helped. The type of dictionary keys are `<class 'sympy.core.symbol.Symbol'>`. And I succeeded getting values like this `stationary_points[Symbol('w')]`

Answer (score -1):

looks like the key names in the dictionary must be either string or number. It should not be a variable. Example,

```
stationary_points = {'w': 542.962336871418, 'b': 0.887349275879595}

print(stationary_points, type(stationary_points), stationary_points.get('w'))
# Output -> {'w': 542.962336871418, 'b': 0.887349275879595} <class 'dict'> 542.962336871418
```

Comment: Please use the right mark down for code sample.